# Grouping structs with enums

Tags: rust

In Rust, how should one go about grouping related structs so that a function signature can accept multiple different types while refering to the concrete type inside the method body?

The following example is contrived for simplicity:

```
enum Command {
    Increment {quantity: u32},
    Decrement {quantity: u32},
}

fn process_command(command: Command) {
    match command {
        Command::Increment => increase(command),
        Command::Decrement => decrease(command),
    };
}

fn increase(increment: Command::Increment) {
    println!("Increasing by: {}.", increment.quantity);
}

fn decrease(decrement: Command::Decrement) {
    println!("Decreasing by: {}.", decrement.quantity);
}

fn main() {
    let input = "Add";
    let quantity = 4;

    let command: Command = match input {
        "Add" => Command::Increment { quantity: quantity },
        "Subtract" => Command::Decrement { quantity: quantity },
        _ => unreachable!(),
    };

    process_command(command);
}
```

Compiling results in the following two errors:

```
src/main.rs:13:24: 13:42 error: found value name used as a type: DefVariant(DefId { krate: 0, node: 4 }, DefId { krate: 0, node: 5 }, true) [E0248]
src/main.rs:13 fn increase(increment: Command::Increment) {
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.rs:17:24: 17:42 error: found value name used as a type: DefVariant(DefId { krate: 0, node: 4 }, DefId { krate: 0, node: 8 }, true) [E0248]
src/main.rs:17 fn decrease(decrement: Command::Decrement) {
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

If I declare the structs seperately, and wrap the structs within a tuple struct (correct terminology?) each within the enum then I get the expected result, but with the verbosity and similar type names all over the place I suspect that I've misunderstood someting:

```
struct Increment {
    quantity: u32,
}

struct Decrement {
    quantity: u32,
}

enum Command {
    Increment(Increment),
    Decrement(Decrement),
}

fn process_command(command: Command) {
    match command {
        Command::Increment(increment) => increase(increment),
        Command::Decrement(decrement) => decrease(decrement),
    };
}

fn increase(increment: Increment) {
    println!("Increasing by: {}.", increment.quantity);
}

fn decrease(decrement: Decrement) {
    println!("Decreasing by: {}.", decrement.quantity);
}

fn main() {
    let input = "Add";
    let quantity = 4;

    let command: Command = match input {
        "Add" => Command::Increment(Increment { quantity: quantity }),
        "Subtract" => Command::Decrement(Decrement { quantity: quantity }),
        _ => unreachable!(),
    };

    process_command(command);
}
```

Running outputs:

```
Increasing by: 4.
```

Is wrapping the struct within an enum type (terminology?) sharing the same name really the best solution? `Command::Increment(Increment { quantity: 7 })`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, this is the best you will get along this line of implementation. An enum is one type only; its variants are purely that—variants, not types.

Another alternative is to use a trait and generics:

```rust
struct Increment {
    quantity: u32,
}

struct Decrement {
    quantity: u32,
}

trait Command {
    fn process(self);
}

impl Command for Increment {
    fn process(self) {
        println!("Increasing by {}", self.quantity);
    }
}

impl Command for Decrement {
    fn process(self) {
        println!("Decreasing by {}", self.quantity);
    }
}
```

Of course, it’s not a direct parallel; if you want to store a `command` of potentially differing types you’ll need to change `process` to take `self: Box<Self>` or `&self`, and you’ll need to work with either `Box<Command>` or `&Command`, but it’s another way of doing things that may suit your requirements. And as far as the definitions are concerned, it’s purer.

Comment: You could also keep the original type and directly give quantity to increase / decrease, since the variant information already has been extracted by the match.

Comment: are there any reasons for "An enum is one type only; its variants are purely that—variants, not types."? IMO, it's perfectly implementable to treat variants as types.

Comment: @xudifsd: at first glance it seems so, but when you get to thinking about type layout you realise that doing so would actually introduce a few rather important problems. Not insurmountable problems, but it would certainly cause surprising behaviour, where the layout of a variant by itself and a variant in the enum were substantially different.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan can you name some?

Comment: Five years later, is there a better way? I'm having precisely the same problem as OP and using a trait is not a solution for me.

Comment: @IndianaKernick: there is no better way, and it’s unlikely that there ever will be.

Comment: A post from 2021, explaining this language choice - which is "for now" as I read it - from Rust point of view: https://github.com/rust-lang/lang-team/issues/122#issuecomment-964459769

Answer (score 21):

I may be misunderstanding your simple example, but remember that you can implement methods on enums directly:

```
enum Command {
    Increment {quantity: u32},
    Decrement {quantity: u32},
}

impl Command {
    fn process(self) {
        match self {
            Command::Increment { quantity } => {
                println!("Increasing by: {}.", quantity)
            },
            Command::Decrement { quantity } => {
                println!("Decreasing by: {}.", quantity)
            },
        };
    }
}

fn main() {
    let input = "Add";
    let quantity = 4;

    let command: Command = match input {
        "Add" => Command::Increment { quantity: quantity },
        "Subtract" => Command::Decrement { quantity: quantity },
        _ => unreachable!(),
    };

    command.process();
}
```

I happen to like this version because it eliminates the redundancy of `process_command(command)`.

Answer (score 3):

What about this one, I am not sure I really understood your issue

```
enum Command {
    Increment (u32),
    Decrement (u32),
}

fn process_command(command: Command) {
    match command {
        Command::Increment(quantity) => increase(quantity),
        Command::Decrement(quantity) => decrease(quantity),
    };
}

fn increase(quantity: u32) {
    println!("Increasing by: {}.", quantity);
}

fn decrease(quantity: u32) {
    println!("Decreasing by: {}.", quantity);
}

fn main() {
    let input = "Add";
    let quantity = 4;

    let command: Command = match input {
        "Add" => Command::Increment (quantity),
        "Subtract" => Command::Decrement (quantity),
        _ => unreachable!(),
    };

    process_command(command);
}
```

Comment: That's less attractive if the variant has lots of fields, doubly so if the enum has methods you'd want to use in `increase` or `decrease`.

Comment: If you have multiple fields, you'll need to have the same number of `Impl` of the corresponding struct anyway. I agree it is less flexible than a struct. I think it is a question of having a centralized `process_command` or several decentralized implementations. Both scenario have pros and cons