# Rust treat two different structs as one

Tags: rust

I have two different structs with similar functions. Suppose that the program choose which struct to take from the user input.
I want to write something like this

```rust
fn main() {
   ... 
   let obj = if a == first {
       first_object //struct First
   } else {
       second_object//struct Second
   };
   
   obj.read();
   obj.write();
   obj.some_another_method();
}
```

I have tried to make an enumeration

```rust
pub enum ObjectKind {
    FirstObject(First),
    SecondObject(Second)
}
```

But I cannot use methods in this case

```rust
let something = ObjectKind::FirstObject(first_object);
something.read()

//no method named `read` found for enum `structs::ObjectKind` in the current scope
//method not found in `structs::ObjectKind`
```

Comment: read https://github.com/shepmaster/rust-mre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I cannot use methods in this case

An `enum` is a proper type in and of itself, it's not a "union" of existing types. You can just define the methods on the `enum` to forward to the relevant object e.g.

```rust
impl ObjectKind {
    fn read(&self) {
        match self {
            FirstObject(f) => f.read()
            SecondObject(s) => s.read()
        }
    }
}
```

as it would probably be a bit repetitive, you can use a [macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-06-macros.html) to make the forwarding easier.

Alternatively, [you might be able to define a *trait* for the common behaviour](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html) and use a [trait object](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html) to dynamically dispatch between the two, but that can be somewhat restrictive.

Comment: Hi. The code isn't working. I tried replace `FirstObject(f) => f.read()` with `FirstObject => FirstObject.read()`, but in the end it gives me `thread 'main' has overflowed its stack
fatal runtime error: stack overflow`

Comment: I think there should be something another instead of `FirstObject(f) `, because the rust gives a `warning variable FirstObject should have a snake case name`

Comment: answer a bad question ? see why we don't ?

Comment: Nevermind. I was able to do what I want with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29088633/grouping-structs-with-enums, but I still will mark this as an answer.