# Is there a way to return multiple values from a Rust match statement?

Tags: rust

I am working through past Advent of Codes as an avenue to learn the language more fully.

As part of one of the problems, I created a function to validate inputs read from a file, returning an enum to tell how to proceed:

```
enum ValidatorReturns {
    BRK,
    CNT,
    VALUES(i32, i32)
}

fn validate_inputs(contents: &mut String) -> ValidatorReturns {...}

fn pt2() -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    let file = File::open("input.input")?;
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(file);
    ...
    loop {
        let mut contents = String::new();
        let _ = reader.read_line(&mut contents)?;
        let mut val1: i32 = 0;  // <-- warning on never-read
        let mut val2: i32 = 0;  // <-- ditto
        let _ = match validate_inputs(&mut contents) {
            ValidatorReturns::BRK => break,
            ValidatorReturns::CNT => continue,
            ValidatorReturns::VALUES(tval1, tval2) => {
                val1 = tval1; // Ugly use of temp var names
                val2 = tval2;
            }
        };
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

This works, but as I've commented, it leads to never-read warnings, has fairly ugly use of temp var names, and feels overall messy.

- Coming from Python, I was inclined to try returning `val1, val2` as a tuple from the match statement, then unpack (rather than `let _ = match ...`, however that didn't work and I was unable to find similar examples anywhere.
- I also tried to declare both variables *in* the match-response block (i.e., `let val1 = tval1;`), and that led to an undeclared-variable compile error (which I can understand why, as it's in a subscope).
- I also considered just returning multiple bools (the first representing `BRK,` the second `CNT,` and then the two validated values); however, this would be messy and seems un-Rust-like.

After some reading of the docs, I refactored it to use a struct as the enum member rather than storing the values directly in the enum:

```
struct ValidatedValues {
    val1: i32,
    val2: i32
}

enum ValidatorReturns {
    BRK,
    CNT,
    VALUES(ValidatedValues)
}

fn validate_inputs(contents: &mut String) -> ValidatorReturns {...}

fn pt2_enum() -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    let file = File::open("input.input")?;
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(file);
    ...
    loop {
        let mut contents = String::new();
        let _ = reader.read_line(&mut contents)?;
        let valvalues = match validate_inputs(&mut contents) {
            ValidatorReturns::BRK => break,
            ValidatorReturns::CNT => continue,
            ValidatorReturns::VALUES(val) => {val}  // <-- Still feels messy
        };
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

It seems like this would be a common pattern with elegant syntax, but having to specify that I want the enum seems rather messy and unconsidered, in contrast to most other Rust syntax; that leads me to wonder if there's a better way to handle this. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29088774) answer to another question has the phrase, "An enum is one type only; its variants are purely that—variants, not types." That makes sense to me, though the solution I've outlined above still strikes me as a somewhat messy solution for what should be a common scenario - especially if it needs to be done per function. For example, the Option enum has `?` or `.unwrap()` to extract the "main" value.

Is using a struct the best/correct way to handle returning multiple values that must be part of an enum? Alternatively, is there a better approach altogether?

Comment: In this specific case, you can use a tuple as in @kmdreko's answer. Another option to get rid of the "never read" warnings is to put `let val1; let val2;` before the `match` (no `mut` and no `= …`), then `val1 = tval1; val2 = tval2;` inside the `match` like you already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a tuple. Here's how:

```
let (val1, val2) = match validate_inputs(&mut contents) {
    ValidatorReturns::BRK => break,
    ValidatorReturns::CNT => continue,
    ValidatorReturns::VALUES(tval1, tval2) => (tval1, tval2),
};
```

Comment: Aha, it was the parens I was missing. I take it then there isn't syntax to imply that the tuple values should be mapped out without specifying so in brackets?

Comment: @user23346441 You mean skip the `=> { ... }` part? Not with a `match`. There is the `let-else` syntax that can pull values out of a pattern directly into scope, but you can't use that here since `BRK` and `CNT` do different things.